# Can I make 2 directories with one line of code?

Tags: java

Is it possible to make 2 directories with java?

example:

```
File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/a/b");
```

Will both directories `a` and `b` be created with this code?

Or should I first create directory `a`  and then create `b`

example:

```
File dira = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/a");
File dirb = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/a/b");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your first command is correct, you need to do this.

```
// if suggested path does not exists
if(!dir.exists()){
   file.mkdirs(); // make the required stucture.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`new File()` itself doesn't create anything. If you want to create several nested directories, you can do this:

```
File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/a/b");
boolean alreadyExists = !dir.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple directory like this.

```
 File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/a/b");
 dir.mkdirs();
```

Hope this solve your problem.